# Is there a way to remove a curse without going to a healer?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I really suck at removing wards so I am often cursed, usually half way through a dungeon when I can't get to a healer. Is there a way to remove the curse myself?

Comment: I need a portable Healer too... I suck at dispelling

Comment: I think the easiest way is just to quicksave before dispelling, and reload if you get a nasty curse or the loot sucks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly, no.  Curses can only be cured by Healers.  You can make a [purification potion](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Purification_Potion) that removes most negative status effects, but it doesn't help with curses.

[The manual](http://cdn.steampowered.com/Manuals/102500/Reckoning_Manual.pdf?t=1328601227) even states:

> Curse:
>   A curse is a long-term negative effect that certain enemies and wards can cast on your character. 
>   Only a healer can remove curses