# How can I get rid of the Negative Effects from dispelling chests?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I need to get rid of three negative effects that I got from unsuccessfully dispelling three chests. The three Negative Effects that I got from them are: Amman's Burning Gaze, Amman's Thunderous Rage, Amman's Icy Touch. Now I have gone to a few Healers. Paid to remove the curses, but there still there under my status and effects. I went to another healer but there is nothing under any of the options to pick from to pay for them to heal. But my negative effects are still there doing damage to my player. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Related, perhaps: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50700/is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-curse-without-going-to-a-healer  Sounds like a glitch, though.

Answer (score 4):

You have to complete the quest "The Unlucky Ones" in Syl and cleanse the Amman amulet.  It's the only way to get rid of those effects.